# Select Distinct for Multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT top 50 column1, column2,column3,column4
FROM (Select Distinct column1,column2, column3, column4 from Table
Where Column2>= '2016-07-01' )
Order By Column2;
```

The result is not what I am expecting. I want to make columns `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`, `Column4` all distinct, meaning each column should have no two identical values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean no value in each of the columns 1 to 4 might repeat?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output

Comment: Yes my result is weird because column2-4 all the result is different values which is good but then the column 1 the result is repeated.

Comment: SELECT top 50 [CLAIM_ID], [TOTAL_CHARGES]
      FROM (Select Distinct CLAIM_ID,TOTAL_CHARGES from Table; I want the values from Claim to be all different and the charges also different.

Comment: No only one entry per CLAIM_ID and no case where two CLAIM_ID's are charged the same amount?

Comment: Yes thats what im looking for. Sorry im new to SQL :D

Comment: But if columns 2 - 4 are different then the row is distinct.    Distinct applies to all columns.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of actual results vs. expected results? The question as it stands is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I've edited your question to make the problem clearer based on your and Kenneth's comments. Please take a look if I've got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get your expected result set using a single Select-statement. IMHO you must create an empty copy of the result table and then use following single-row Insert to prevent any duplicate values. Repeat this until you get the expected *n* rows.

```
insert into result_table
select top 1 column1, column2,column3,column4
from base_table as t1
where Column2>= '2016-07-01'
  and not exists 
  ( select * 
    from result_table as t2
     where Column2>= '2016-07-01'
       and
        (  t1.column1 = t2.column1 -- unique data in each column
        or t1.column2 = t2.column2
        or t1.column3 = t2.column3
        or t1.column4 = t2.column4
        )
  )
 Order By Column2;
```

Comment: Yes, iterative approach seems to me the only solution, even though it's not very reliable. For instance, if you tried to apply this method to this two-column set: `(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)` to select two distinct rows, you might only get one if the first selected row happened to be `(1, 3)`. (But you would get two if the first one was `(1, 2)`.)

Comment: @AndriyM: Of course, this is a kind of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your query...

SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,column3,column4

FROM (Select top 50 colum1,clumn2, column3, column4 from Table)X

Where Column2>= '2016-07-01' 
Order By Column2;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the Top 50 distinct combinations of C1-C4, Steve is close.  However, having the Top 50 inside of, or before, the DISTINCT may cause fewer than 50 returned results if there are any duplicates found.
Instead, you would want to return a full list of all distinct value combinations, then limit it down to only the top 50.

When doing things like this, I generally avoid using the DISTINCT command.
Instead, use GROUP BY.  It will do essentially the same thing and will add more control if you want to expand results later.

As for your query, I'm not seeing a closing parenthesis where there should be one so I don't know where the WHERE and ORDER BY clause are actually supposed to be.  I would suggest putting them in your inner query to limit the results returned for the TOP 50.

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (colum1 VARCHAR(30), clumn2 VARCHAR(30), column3 VARCHAR(30), column4 VARCHAR(30))

    SELECT TOP 50 *
    FROM(
        SELECT colum1,clumn2, column3, column4
        FROM @Table
        WHERE clumn2 >= '2016-07-01'
        GROUP BY colum1,clumn2, column3, column4
    ) x
    ORDER BY clumn2
```

Comment: You are right about SELECT DISTINCT after SELECT TOP 50 potentially resulting in fewer rows than 50. Your GROUP BY replacement, however, is no different from the OP's query in terms of results and is, therefore, not an answer to their question.

Comment: I don't deny that. In this instance, group by is exactly the same as DISTINCT.  I failed to see what is wrong with the OP query given his requirements.  It looks like additional comments were added that might clue us in more.

Comment: Yes, I myself, too, understood their problem only after reading the comments.